# Best practices for providing Swagger Codegen clients

Tags: swagger-codegen

I have a bunch of Swaggerized services.    These services all *talk to* (call) each other.   The services, of course, have API versions.    Ultimately our goal is to not make incompatible changes to the REST APIs, but given that we're in early-stages (nothing in production,...) we are quite prepared to "correct mistakes".

I have not found any good treatise on how to organize the services with regard to Maven projects and Swagger Codegen.

It seems to me that each service wants the following artifacts:

1. A WAR file to deploy the service
2. A Swagger Codegen-generated client API in a Jar file that would be imported by consumers of the API.

We would also want the client API jar in our own Maven repository so it can be brought in as a Maven dependency.

So my questions are:

- Is this how it is typically done?
- KEY QUESTION: Is there a way for me to generate a client from the Swagger-annotated resource classes.   I'm looking avoid having to DEPLOY the service in order to get a Swagger Specification File.
- Would we would generate the client JAR as a SECOND artifact of the service WAR Maven project or...
- Should we have a separate Maven project for the JAR file that imports stuff from the service (remember that's a war file, not a JAR file).   I suppose it might scan the Swaggerized Resource classes to produce a Swagger specification file and then generate the client from that?
- Something else entirely?

Additional points:

1. Right now, we only have Java clients, but we might have other clients in the future

Comment: I've worked on a system where they had the docs uploaded on a server and were downloaded upon built, too make sure all consumers were compatible.

Comment: @daniu   OK, that's interesting.  So rather than "pull" the API client, you pull the Swagger Specification.    Generate it in the project that consumes the API?  That makes a lot of sense because that way you can write a API consumer in any supported langauge.

Comment: Well it was consumer driven contract, ie the consumer was the one putting up the spec and the producer was the one responsible to conform to it, but yeah pretty much same thing.